# How to make a thread safe in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, increment

i have a calculation, but my calculation is not thread-safe, it must be using increment or increment_counter, but I have no idea how to implement it. here's my code

```
def create
if @purchase.check_quantity(@product, purchase_params[:quantity].to_i)
  return render :new  
end

#calculation is not thread-safe
new_quantity = @product.quantity - purchase_params[:quantity].to_i

@purchase.assign_attributes(purchase_params)
if @purchase.save
   @product.update(:quantity => new_quantity)
   redirect_to product_url(@product)
else
  flash[:error] = @purchase.errors.full_messages.join(', ')
  render :new
end
```

end

Comment: By thread safe are you refering to? Another person could also hit update and get the same quantity value?

Comment: Maybe this article will help you: https://www.toptal.com/ruby/ruby-concurrency-and-parallelism-a-practical-primer but I do not recommend trying to do multithreading in ruby. Anything that must run asynchronously should be done using ActiveJob or Sidekiq

Comment: Yes, it will get conflict if another person hit update, any idea how to solve it?

Comment: see my answer, reload your object from the database just before you make calculations on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already noticed that you might run into race conditions in which two requests to your application enter that method almost at the same time. Both read `@product.quantity`, both calculate `new_quantity` and then you end up with one of those requests writing the new value into the database, and the other, slightly slower request overrides that value.

There are two approaches to solve this issue.

1. Lock the record for an update. Another process trying to update the same record at the same time will then raise an error. Ruby on Rails supports [`Locking::Optimistic`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Optimistic.html) and [`Locking::Pessimistic`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html). It depends a bit on your specific use-case what might be the better approach.
2. An alternative might be to do the update in SQL that atomically updates records. Rails has the method [`update_counters`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/ClassMethods.html#method-i-update_counters) that would allow you to calculate and update the record in the database like this:

   ```
   Product.update_counters(@product.id, quantity: -purchase_params[:quantity].to_i)
   ```

   But this way might (depending on what your `check_quantity` internally does) might still cause race condition issues because the check in that method will not be aware of any other requests passing the check immediately before and updating the database immediately after.

Both methods might help to solve the issue. But which method to choose depends on your specific use case and the level of security, user experience, and data integrity you need.

Comment: I think what he needs is .reload just before running any sort of calculations

Comment: The more traffic your application has, the more likely you will run into race conditions. And No, a `reload` would not help in the case of a race condition. With a `reload` you could still have two different requests reaching the `reload` at the same time and then both requests will do the calculation based on the same old value. But because the update into the database is atomic only the result of one request is saved because the second update overrides the first.

Comment: yes, this is what I've looking for, thank you so much, sir!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what about your code is "not thread-safe" but I don't believe your issue is thread safety.

If you think the `@purchase` or `@product` objects are changing just before that code gets hit, I'd recommend using [`.reload`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/reload). If you believe your calculation needs to run asynchronously you need to consider using an async job framework like [ActiveJob](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) or [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq).

Comment: Moving the logic into a background job would only solve the issue when your setup only allows one background job at a time. But most setups usually configure multiple workers/threads at the same time and that means the code is still vulnerable to the same race condition I described in my answer.